# Get async variable return empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook-web-addins, yeoman-generator

I am trying to create an add-in for the outlook windows application.
The following code should copy the email body to the clipboard, but it doesn't do that.
I need to press the run button two times in order to get the content copied, but I need to copy the content from the first time!
What is wrong with my code?

```
var messageBody = "";
export async function run() {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
        Office.CoercionType.Text,
        function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                messageBody = asyncResult.error;
            } else {
                messageBody = asyncResult.value;
            }
        });

    copyToClipboard(messageBody)
}

function copyToClipboard(text) {
    var copyhelper = document.createElement("input");
    copyhelper.className = 'copyhelper'
    document.body.appendChild(copyhelper);
    copyhelper.value = text;
    copyhelper.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(copyhelper);
}
```

Comment: you would put `copyToClipboard(messageBody)` INSIDE `function(asyncResults) {...}`

Comment: I would suggest reading this: [How to return an asynchronous value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) as the issue of asynchronous timing is covered there.  Basically, your function `run()` returns BEFORE the asynchronous value has been retrieved so you are trying to use `messageBody` before it has a value in it.  You will need to communicate back the asynchronous result with either a callback or a promise or an event or you can use the async value inside the callback where it is retrieved.